# Counting row multiple exec stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure which calling another procedure
something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST_LOOPING]
  @ID nvarchar(50) = null
AS
BEGIN
    exec proc_1 @ID
    exec proc_2 @ID
    exec proc_3 @ID
END
```

can I get total row result from test looping? and show it as additional select in the end not as output

NB : can the result shown at first row? 
like this

```
Total
275
result for proc_1
result for proc_2
result fro proc_3
```

Comment: Modify the underlying stored procedures to return the number of row in an `OUT` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST_LOOPING]
  @ID nvarchar(50) = null
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @c INT = 0;

    exec proc_1 @ID
    SET @c += @@ROWCOUNT;
    exec proc_2 @ID
    SET @c += @@ROWCOUNT;
    exec proc_3 @ID
    SET @c += @@ROWCOUNT;

    SELECT @c AS Total
END
```

EDIT:

I don't recommend using it, but it is possible:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST_LOOPING]
      @ID nvarchar(50) = null
    AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @c INT = 0;


    CREATE TABLE #temp1(cols... )
    CREATE TABLE #temp3(cols... )
    CREATE TABLE #temp3(cols... )

    INSERT INTO #temp1(cols ...)
    exec proc_1 @ID
    SET @c += @@ROWCOUNT;

    INSERT INTO #temp2(cols ...)
    exec proc_2 @ID
    SET @c += @@ROWCOUNT;

    INSERT INTO #temp3(cols ...)
    exec proc_3 @ID
    SET @c += @@ROWCOUNT;

    SELECT @c AS Total

    SELECT *
    FROM #temp1

    SELECT *
    FROM #temp2

    SELECT *
    FROM #temp3
END
```

Another solution as `Gordon Linoff` suggest is to modify each stored procedure to return records number in `OUTPUT` parameter, but even then if you want total record number as first result set them you need to store data in intermediate temp tables.

Comment: I think this is making pretty heavy assumptions about the implementation of three stored procedures.

Comment: ehm thx for right answer, but can the Total show at first row? forget for this problem :')

Comment: @Mike If you first store result set in temp tables then yes, but I don't recommend it